# Formatting the string to a particular date format

Tags: android, simpledateformat

How can I convert this String `2013-09-02T17:40:36+00:00` to this format `Mon Sep,2 2013 5:40 PM` Output should be of type String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Parse the `String` into `Date` using `SimpleDateFormat`
  (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
  The Format should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz`
- Format the Date with the SimpleDateFormat  `EEE MMM, F yyyy hh:mm a`

Comment: Thanks. I've used this format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first covert into a Date and then again convert it into a string you want

```
String dtStart = "2013-09-02T17:40:36+00:00";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
 Date date;
try {  
   date = format.parse(dtStart);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}

SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM,dd yyyy HH:mm aa");  
try {  
 String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
 System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + datetime); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write something like this:

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EEE MMM, F yyyy hh:mm a");

        dateFormatter.setLenient(false);

        Date today = new Date();
        String curr_date = dateFormatter.format(today);

        System.out.println("today's date is::" + curr_date);
```

Also you can refer to the following link for future reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html